# Java selenium avoiding iframe address bar element

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

Currently I wrote a short program that traverses through a page and looks for web elements with the tagname = "input", then uses sendkeys to send data to the element, then submits it. The problem I have is that although it works most of the time, if I have an iframe on the page, and I traverse through the webpage looking for an element with the tagname = "input", it focuses on the addressbar of the iframe and sends data to it, then tries to submit it causing an error (when I printed the tagname of the addressbar in the iframe, it printed out "input" on the console).

Is there a way to avoid the addressbar on an iframe from being picked up as an element with the tagname = "input"?

Im using the following to check if an element has tagname of "input":

```
    List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
    int mainSize = element.size();


    for ( int j = 0; j < mainSize; j++ ) {
        if(frameElement.get(j).getTagName().toString().equals("input")){
        //do something
        }
    }
```

Some notes:

> -This occurs when going through the webpage elements searching through tagnames for "input" elements BEFORE switching to the iframe element with the switchTo() method.

Comment: Could you share the html for the iframe which contains address bar element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid the address bar, you can introduce one more check to ensure that the **input** element is not an address bar. Following is the updated code to achieve this:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
        int mainSize = element.size();


        for ( int j = 0; j < mainSize; j++ ) {
            if(element.get(j).getTagName().toString().equals("input") && 
                    !element.get(j).getAttribute("class").equals("urlbar")){
            //do something
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE 1**

We can retry when unexpected browser search bar appears. Try following:

```
 List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
        int mainSize = element.size();


        for ( int j = 0; j < mainSize; j++ ) {
            if(element.get(j).getTagName().toString().equals("input") && 
                    !element.get(j).getAttribute("class").equals("urlbar")){
            //do something
                try {
                element.get(j).sendKeys(somedata); 
                element.get(j).submit();
            } catch (WebDriverException we) {
                System.out.println("It seems browser search bar has been appeared. Retrying...");
                //Pressing escape key to get rid of browser search bar
                element.get(j).sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
                //Retrying
                element.get(j).sendKeys(somedata); 
                element.get(j).submit();
            }
        }
     }
```

Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Comment: Hey thanks alot, this solves the issue, but I now have a new problem, it seems the code picks up the browsers "search-this-page feature" (the ctrl+f when on the browser on windows) and sends data to it. Is there a way to skip this as well? Im using firefox as the webdriver with gecko

Comment: Could you elaborate more about this new issue?

Comment: Did you mean that you press ctrl+f during execution?

Comment: I'm not sure if this explains it better, but on the firebox browser on windows, when a user presses "ctrl+f" on their keyboard a search bar appears somewhere on the browser client. The issue is, the code is assuming that this search bar is another web element with the tagname = "input". So when I run the code it goes to the searchbar even if the user has not opened it on the browser and sends data to it, then submits it and another error appears. I would like to avoid getting the searchbar as well. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I understood the issue. However, when I try to press ctrl + f in my firefox browser a search bar appears, but that search bar cannot be recognized by selenium. This might be the issue of lost focus. Could you share the code where you are entering the data?

Comment: Within the if statement that you have provided, I have the following code (simplified from my original one because its a bit long): if(element.get(j).getTagName().toString().equals("input") && 
                    !element.get(j).getAttribute("class").equals("urlbar")){
    
    System.out.println(element.get(j).getTagName());
    element.get(j).sendKeys(somedata);
    element.get(j).submit(); //error occurs here after submit is pressed because the current element "input" is the searchbar
   }

Comment: For some reason selenium is picking up the searchbar for me on firefox, and assuming it has the tagname = "input"

Comment: So that searchbar is automatically appearing we are not pressing ctrl+f. Correct? Additionally, could you put `System.out.println(element.get(j).getAttribute("innerHTML"));` before entering data and share the output that appear just before it enters data into search bar?

Comment: Yes, the searchbar seems to automatically pop-up without the user pressing anything. I also got an empty output when I placed it before the element.get(j).sendKeys(somedata);

Comment: That seems to do the trick, much appreciated, catching the error produced by the searchbar seems to be the best approach to avoiding the searchbar problem, thanks again